# check boxes after filter

Tags: php, laravel

am trying to check checkbox after i search something.
i did something like this

```
   @if (request()->discount)
                            checked
                            @endif
```

and it's working but in categories if i check one of categories and filter by it then all categories are checked.

```
  <input id="subCats-{{$s->id}}" name="category[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $s->id }}"   
                            @if (request()->category)
                            checked
                            @endif
                            >
```

and am having problem with

```
       <input type="checkbox" name="level" value="0" id="lvl-0"
                                @if (request()->level == 0)
                            checked
                            @endif
```

it's always is checked because if i don't requests its null and it's thinks that its 0 i trying (request()->level === 0) but it's still don't works.

Comment: side note: if you are using Laravel-9 you can do `@checked(request()->category)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input id="subCats-{{$s->id}}" name="category[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $s->id }}"   
@if (request()->category != "" && in_array($s->id,explode(','request()->category)))
checked
@endif
>
```

if you are padding multiple category comma separated (,)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="level" value="0" id="lvl-0"  @isset(request()->level) checked  @endif>
```

Comment: thanks for response. am getting error when filtering category " explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, array given "

Comment: and i have 3 inputs with level with values 0 / 1 / 2

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="subCats-{{$s->id}}" name="category[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $s->id }}"   
@if (request()->category != "" && in_array($s->id,request()->category))
checked
@endif
>
```

Use this instead